# Tool for editing Project File to add Import Tag

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any tool within Visual Studio IDE to edit <Import Project ... /> settings?

Currently we have to open project file in notepad and update the project setting manually.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I want to added import setting for stylecop and stylecop targets are placed within the project directory and not picked up from a central location. It is hard to manage the path sometimes. So need a way to edit it using any UI.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio right click your project, select Unload Project, right click again and select Edit ProjectName.csproj.

When you're done, right click again and select Reload Project.

Comment: This will load project file in XML format but I need a way to edit using any UI to select the Path of Stylecop target.

Comment: Right click Add Reference... Is that what you're looking for? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: No. I want to Edit this line   <Import Project="..\Dependencies\Microsoft StyleCop\V4.4.0\Microsoft.StyleCop.targets" /> through UI

Comment: That's an MSBuild import. You could try http://www.msbuildexplorer.com/, but you're probably better off learning the syntax and using a text editor.